# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /opt/ml/input/data/train/label_map.pbtxt; No such file or directory

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, amazon-sagemaker

I've been following this tutorial on [Training and deploying models using TensorFlow 2 with the Object Detection API on Amazon SageMaker](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/training-and-deploying-models-using-tensorflow-2-with-the-object-detection-api-on-amazon-sagemaker/) but keep on getting the above error when attempting to train the model using estimator.fit(inputs) in train_model.ipynb. All of the code for the tutorial is available at: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-tensorflow-object-detection-api

The label_map.pbtxt, train.records and validation.records files were successfully created in my bucket (at s3://bucket/data/bees/tfrecords), and I've adjusted my pipeline.config file to contain:

```
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "/opt/ml/input/data/train/label_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/opt/ml/input/data/train/train.records"
  }
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "/opt/ml/input/data/train/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/opt/ml/input/data/train/validation.records"
  }
}
```

I'm completely new to Amazon Sagemaker and containers but have followed the walkthrough to a tee, so I'm lost as to why it's failing. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the input paths are pointing to a local folder when they should be pointing to the S3 bucket. Your pipeline.config file should look like this:

```
train_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "s3://bucket/data/bees/tfrecordslabel_map.pbtxt"
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "s3://bucket/data/bees/tfrecords/train.records"
  }
}

eval_input_reader: {
  label_map_path: "s3://bucket/data/bees/tfrecords/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_epochs: 1
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "s3://bucket/data/bees/tfrecords/validation.records"
  }
}
```